# Sign In With Google is Not Working in Released Version of Application with Google Developer Console

Tags: android, google-signin, google-developers-console

I have used credentials for debug application which is obtain from android studio itself. Now I have published my application in play store. When I am running application in debug mode, It is working fine. But for Released version which is in play store it is not working Google Sign In Properly.

I have obtain new SHA-1 Key from Play Store console and created new credentials into Google Developer Console but same issue I am facing.

Please help me out.

SignIn Result:failed code= 10

Comment: What is you sign in failure status code?

Comment: @RazvanS.   Status code is 10

Comment: According to the documentation (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes#public-static-final-int-developer_error) code 10 is DEVELOPER_ERROR The application is misconfigured. This error is not recoverable and will be treated as fatal. The developer should look at the logs after this to determine more actionable information.

Comment: @RazvanS. I have released apk into play store and I have created new OAuth ID in developer console with new SHA-1 Key. Then also it shows same error.

Comment: Well, you need to add some logging so that you can get more details on the specific error.